# How can I calculate this limit? ( I tried l'Hopital and failed )

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I have to calculate this : $$ \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2-x}{x^3}e^{(x-1)/x^2} $$ Can somebody help me?

Comment: How did l'hopsital fail?

Comment: If you apply it twice then it almost returns to it's original form.

Comment: The tag ([tag:limit-theorems]) is intended for questions about limit theorems in probability theory and not for questions about determining limits of sequences or functions, see the [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/limit-theorems/info) and the tag-excerpt. (The tag-excerpt is also shown when you are adding a tag to a question.)

Answer (score 4):

Hint: It may be fruitful to substitute $\alpha = 1/x$, in which case you obtain the limit

$$ \lim_{ \alpha \rightarrow \infty} \left(2 - \frac{1}{\alpha} \right) \alpha^3 e^{\alpha - \alpha^2} $$

I should note that, here, I'm taking your limit to in fact be the limit as $x$ approaches $0$ from the positive direction. If you're intending for your limit to be two-sided, then you should think about why that would cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

Letting $w=1/x$, we have
$$
\lim_{x\downarrow 0}\frac{2-x}{x^3}e^{(x-1)/x^2} = \lim_{w\to+\infty} \left(2 - \frac 1 w \right) w^3 e^{w^2\left(\frac 1 w - 1\right)} = \lim_{w\to+\infty} (2w^3 - w^2) e^{w-w^2}
$$
$$
= \lim_{w\to+\infty} \frac{2w^3-w^2}{e^{w^2-w}}.
$$
L'Hopital should handle that.

Maybe I'll post something on $x\uparrow 0$ later . . .

Answer (score -1):

$$\lim_{x\to0}(f(x)g(x)) = \lim_{x\to0}(f(x)) \cdot \lim_{x\to0}(g(x))  $$

With that being said you can let $f(x) =  (2-x)/x^3 $ and $ g(x) = e^{(x-1)/x^2}  $

I hope this helps.

Comment: It doesn't because the first limit is infinite and the second limit is 0 and you can't multiply them.

Comment: Ah right I didn't even really think about the limits.